# How to include this code to automatically populate checkboxes from a dynamic data

Tags: vba, checkbox, activex

I have one of the sheets with 5 columns, I want to automatically create ActiveX check-boxes in another sheet, and its caption to be the dynamic data values for example.

**Sheet1** includes the dynamic data Range G,H,I,J lets say values 10,20,30,40

I want in **Sheet2**, Cell E2 A checkbox automatically created once there is data in Sheet1 Range G,H,I,J

```
'Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim NewChkBx As MSForms.CheckBox
    Dim rngSource As Range
    Dim rngSource2 As Range
    Dim rngSource3 As Range
    Dim rngSource4 As Range
    Dim rngSource5 As Range
    Dim Quantity_definition_1 As Range
    Dim Quantity_definition_2 As Range
    Dim Quantity_definition_3 As Range
    Dim Quantity_definition_4 As Range
    Dim Quantity_definition_5 As Range
    Dim TopPos As Integer
    Dim MaxWidth As Long

    With Worksheets("AppSyncData")

        Set rngSource = .Range("F2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp))
        Set rngSource2 = .Range("G2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp))
        Set rngSource3 = .Range("H2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp))
        Set rngSource4 = .Range("I2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp))
        Set rngSource5 = .Range("J2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp))

    End With

    TopPos = 15

    MaxWidth = 0

    For Each Quantity_definition_1 In rngSource
        If Quantity_definition_1.Value <> "" Then
            Set NewChkBx = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1")
            With NewChkBx
                .Caption = Quantity_definition_1.Value
                .Left = 5
                .Top = TopPos
                .AutoSize = True
                If .Width > MaxWidth Then MaxWidth = .Width
            End With
            TopPos = TopPos + 15
        End If
    Next Quantity_definition_1

    TopPos = 15

    For Each Quantity_definition_2 In rngSource2
        If Quantity_definition_2.Value <> "" Then
            Set NewChkBx = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1")
            With NewChkBx
                .Caption = Quantity_definition_2.Value
                .Left = 50
                .Top = TopPos
                .AutoSize = True
                If .Width > MaxWidth Then MaxWidth = .Width
            End With
            TopPos = TopPos + 15
        End If

     Next Quantity_definition_2

        TopPos = 15

    For Each Quantity_definition_3 In rngSource3
        If Quantity_definition_3.Value <> "" Then
            Set NewChkBx = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1")
            With NewChkBx
                .Caption = Quantity_definition_3.Value
                .Left = 95
                .Top = TopPos
                .AutoSize = True
                If .Width > MaxWidth Then MaxWidth = 500
            End With
            TopPos = TopPos + 15
        End If
    Next Quantity_definition_3

    TopPos = 15

     For Each Quantity_definition_4 In rngSource4
        If Quantity_definition_4.Value <> "" Then
            Set NewChkBx = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1")
            With NewChkBx
                .Caption = Quantity_definition_4.Value
                .Left = 135
                .Top = TopPos
                .AutoSize = True
                If .Width > MaxWidth Then MaxWidth = 500
            End With
            TopPos = TopPos + 15
        End If
    Next Quantity_definition_4

    TopPos = 15

     For Each Quantity_definition_5 In rngSource5
        If Quantity_definition_5.Value <> "" Then
            Set NewChkBx = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1")
            With NewChkBx
                .Caption = Quantity_definition_5.Value
                .Left = 180
                .Top = TopPos
                .AutoSize = True
                If .Width > MaxWidth Then MaxWidth = 500

                End With

            TopPos = TopPos + 15
        End If
    Next Quantity_definition_5


    Me.Width = MaxWidth + 40

    Me.Height = TopPos + 40


End Sub
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I am sorry, I will remove it right now

Answer (score 0):

So here is my version.

```
Private Sub GenerateCheckboxes()
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("AppSyncData")

    Dim ws2 As Excel.Worksheet
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Checkboxes")

    Dim vCheckBoxLefts As Variant
    vCheckBoxLefts = Array(5, 50, 95, 135, 180)

    Dim lLeftLoop As Long: lLeftLoop = 0

    Const TopPos As Long = 15
    Dim lTopOffset As Long
    Dim lMaxBottom As Long

    Dim lMaxRight As Long
    lMaxRight = 0


    Dim lColumnLoop As Long
    For lColumnLoop = 6 To 10

        lTopOffset = 0

        Dim rngSource As Excel.Range
        Set rngSource = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, lColumnLoop), ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, lColumnLoop).End(xlUp))

        Dim vSource As Variant
        vSource = rngSource.Value

        Dim vQuantityDefinition As Variant
        For Each vQuantityDefinition In vSource
            If Len(vQuantityDefinition) > 0 Then

                Dim chkNew As Excel.CheckBox
                Set chkNew = ws2.CheckBoxes.Add(362.25, 92.25, 166.5, 48)
                chkNew.Caption = vQuantityDefinition
                chkNew.Left = vCheckBoxLefts(lLeftLoop)
                chkNew.Top = TopPos + lTopOffset
                If chkNew.Left + chkNew.Width > lMaxRight Then lMaxRight = chkNew.Left + chkNew.Width
                If chkNew.Top + chkNew.Height > lMaxBottom Then lMaxBottom = chkNew.Top + chkNew.Height

            lTopOffset = lTopOffset + 15

            End If
        Next vQuantityDefinition

        lLeftLoop = lLeftLoop + 1
    Next lColumnLoop


End Sub
```

Comment: I was asking if I can embed this int he sheet,

now I have managed to do it using the below code, but everytime the code clears the reffernces for the cells

For Each cel2 In myRange2

If cel2.Value <> "0" Then

    Set cb = cel2.Worksheet.CheckBoxes.Add(cel2.Left + cel2.Width / 2 - 8.25, _
            cel2.Top + cel2.Height / 2 - 8.25, 0, 0)
    cb.Text = cel2.Value
    cb.LinkedCell = cel2.Address(0, 0)
    cb.Name = "cb" & cb.LinkedCell
    cel2.NumberFormat = ";;;"
    End If

Comment: I have amended my code to add checkboxes to the worksheet and didn't see your last comment.

Comment: Any feedback, Hany?